# Pointer issue in C

Tags: c, pointers

Greetings,
I am trying to learn pointers in C, I simply want my "addtwo" function to add 2 to every element of the input integer array, yet I get odd compilation errors, here is the non-pointer version which indeed won't properly compile.

```
addtwo(int *arr[]) {
    int i=0;
    for(;i< sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] + 2;
    }
}

main() {
    int myarray[] = {1,2,3,4};
    addtwo(myarray);
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`addtwo(int *arr[])` should be `addtwo(int *arr)`

You cannot use sizeof to get the size of an array from a pointer. Typically you would either pass the size of the array as a separate arg or have some special value marking the last element.

Comment: sizeof will not work within the body of addtwo. So not a complete answer.

Answer (score 7):

You've some problems. First, you try to pass a `int*` to a parameter that's type `int**`. That won't work. Give it type `int*`:

```
void addtwo(int *arr){
    int i=0;
    for(;i< sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i] + 2;
    }
}
```

Then, you need to pass the size in an additional argument. The problem is, that when you pass arrays, you really pass just a pointer (the compiler will make up a temporary pointer that points to the array's first element). So you need to keep track of the size yourself:

```
void addtwo(int *arr, int size){
    int i=0;
    for(;i<size;i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i] + 2;
    }
}


int main(void) {
    int myarray[] = {1,2,3,4};
    addtwo(myarray, sizeof myarray / sizeof myarray[0]);
}
```

Now it will work. Also put the return type before them. Some compilers may reject your code, since it doesn't comply to the most recent C Standard anymore, and has long been deprecated (omitting the return type was the way you coded with the old K&R C).

Comment: Alternatively, pass the array as an int[4] instead of int*.

Comment: You cannot do that in C :( the best match for that would be to pass a pointer to the array. then it would look like void addtwo(int (*arr)[4]) ... addtwo(&myarray) . but you could not pass any other size, and it looks rather scary :)

Comment: Have a look on this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779910/should-i-use-char-argv-or-char-argv-in-c/780147#780147

Comment: Oops, you're right, although saying that you "cannot" do that isn't quite true -- you can still declare the parameter as int[4], but it's no different from int[] or int*.

Comment: indeed :) i meant to say you cannot pass it as an int[4] . Of course nothing stops you from declaring the parameter as an int[4] :)

Answer (score 3):

Not to do with the compile error, but...

You have to pass sizeof(arr) to the function instead of calling it in the function.  When an array is passed to a function, C no longer sees it as an array, but as a single pointer to memory, so that sizeof(arr) as you are calling it now, will return the size of the pointer arr, which is most likely 4.

Here's what I mean in code:

```
void addtwo(int *arr, int size){
    int i=0;
    for(;i< size;i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i] + 2;
    }
}

int main(){
    int myarray[] = {1,2,3,4};
    addtwo(myarray, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: +1 It was correct initially. Post the edit, main is missing a return in the function signature line. The actual return 0; can be dropped though.

Answer (score 1):

In C a notation int *arr[] is the same as int** arr.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a pointer to the first element of the array and the array size. Array types decay to pointers in the context of function parameters. Try:

```
void addtwo(int *arr, size_t size){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i] + 2;
    }
}


int main() {
    int v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 };
    addtwo(v, sizeof v / sizeof v[ 0 ]);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though others already gave the correct response, basically you have an array of pointers when you have

```
int *arr[]
```

I doubt that is what you want.  If you have

```
int arr[]
```

then that will also be equivalent to

```
int *arr
```

Answer (score 0):

addtwo argument declaration really reads:

*arr is an array of pointers to integer*

when you probably really want

*a pointer to an array of integers*

"[How to Read C Declarations](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/CS652/How+To+Read+C+Declarations?showComments=true&showCommentArea=true)" has really helped me to grok the topic a while ago, maybe it will do the same for you.