# Curiosity about passing a function as parameter - C++

Tags: c++, methods, parameter-passing

suppose you have the following method:

```
double * myMethod(double (*f)(double[]), double *x, int size)
{
    //do something and return
}
```

Why can't I write as follows?

```
double * myMethod(double (*f)(double *), double *x, int size)
{
    //do something and return
}
```

replacing the [] with * ?

Comment: Why? There are better solutions, less complex and easier to understand and debug.

Comment: Could you give some details about the compiler, its version and the error message you get? It works for me with gcc 4.6.3

Comment: Somewhat of a tangent, but you shouldn't normally need to use function pointers in C++, except perhaps to interface to C code -- they're a horrible artifact inherited from the C language. Instead, use `std::function`, or templates and lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but because arrays deprecate the pointers, they actually have the same signature, so if you're getting an error it's because you're trying to redefine the function:

http://ideone.com/E1Z7B works because I renamed the second function.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192068/c-char-argv-vs-char-argv for a similar question.