# Double pointer in int main

Tags: c, pointers

I am still trying to understand about doublepointers.

I do know how double pointers are usually used in most cases like

```
void foo(char **ptr)
{
 // blah
}

int main(void)
{
    char *ptr;
    foo(&ptr);
}
```

However i have no idea what one does differently than the other

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) //Double pointer

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // Single
```

Comment: This text explains pointers and has helped me alot. Might be interesting?

http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use char** argv or char* argv\[\] in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779910/should-i-use-char-argv-or-char-argv-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used as a parameter to a function, an array designator `[]` is exactly the same as a pointer. The two declarations you have for `main` are in fact identical.

There are times when the two different syntaxes mean different things, but this isn't one of them.

In this case it means you have an array of pointers. Each pointer points to an array of characters.  `argv[0]` is a pointer to the first `char*` string, `argv[1]` is a pointer to the second `char*` string, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I feel your pain! It took me a long time to convince myself that I should treat them exactly the same.

argv[1] points to the first parameter, argv[argc-1] points to the final parameter. Yes, all you sharpshooters, that's true iff argc > 0.

That's my formula and I'm stickin' to it.