# Passing an array of strings as an argument into a double pointer parameter

Tags: c, pointers, arguments, parameter-passing, implicit-conversion

For the following code:

```
char* fcn(char **para){

}

int main(void){
  char *arg[] = {"XX", "YY", "ZZ"};
  char *s = fcn(arg); 
}
```

Why is it that when we pass the argument into the function in `char *s = fcn(arg);`, we don't need to do `&arg`? `arg[]` seems to me a single pointer, so shouldn't we do `&ptr` for it to be referenced by a double pointer as in the parameter of fcn(): `char* fcn(char **para)`?

Comment: What does the function do?! It even returns nothing though its return type is not void.

Comment: Sorry, it does something, but I removed everything else just so that I can highlight my point better. It should just return a string of type `char *`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing a pointer to a char array as an argument to a function - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032885/passing-a-pointer-to-a-char-array-as-an-argument-to-a-function-c)

Answer (score 1):

An array when used in most expressions *decays* into a pointer to the first element of the array.

`arg` is declared as an array of `char *`, so a pointer to an element of the array has type `char **`.

If you were to use `&arg`, that is one of the few times an array does *not* decay and the expression would have type `char *(*)[3]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of 3 elements of type `char *`.  This is very different from `char **`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array then used in expressions it is implicitly converted (with rare exceptions) to a pointer to its first element.

On the other hand, a function parameter having an array type is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the array element type.

For example if you declared a function like

```
char* fcn( char *para[] );
```

then the compiler will adjust the function declaration the following way

```
char* fcn( char **para );
```

You even may include the both declarations in your program though the compiler can issue a message that there are redundant declarations.

So if you have a function like this

```
char* fcn( char *para[] );
```

and in the caller you have an array like this

```
char *arg[] = {"XX", "YY", "ZZ"};
```

then the function parameter and the array declared in the caller have array types with the same element type. So you may call the function like

```
fcn( arg );
```

The array used as the argument is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.

The type of array elements is `char *`. So a pointer to an element of the array will have the type `char **`.

That is this function call

```
fcn( arg );
```

is equivalent to

```
fcn( &arg[0] );
```

Dereferencing the pointer you will get the first element of the array having the type `char *`.

If you will write the expression

```
&arg
```

then the type of the expression will be `char * ( * )[3]`. Dereferencing the pointer you will get the original array of the type `char *[3]`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( char **arg )
{
    printf( "sizeof( *arg ) = %zu\n", sizeof( *arg ) );
}

void g( char * ( *arg )[3] )
{
    printf( "sizeof( *arg ) = %zu\n", sizeof( *arg ) );
}

int main(void) 
{
    char * arg[] = { "XX", "YY", "ZZ" };
    
    f( arg );
    g( &arg );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
sizeof( *arg ) = 8
sizeof( *arg ) = 24
```