# What is a char** argv[] in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am clear about the difference between char* argv[] and char** argv (as explained, for instance, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779910/should-i-use-char-argv-or-char-argv-in-c)).

But what kind of type is char** argv[] ? A pointer to a pointer to a pointer of chars? And what would that be, when used to pass arguments to the program?

For the record, the type occurs in the following declaration of a C++ library I am trying to interface to  Python:

```
/** Initialize the Stage library. Stage will parse the argument
  array looking for parameters in the conventional way. */
  void Init( int* argc, char** argv[] );
```

Comment: Hopefully it's a typo

Comment: Same as a `char ***argv` in that context FWIW, but I'm guessing from `main`, `argv` points somewhere else after you pass `&argv`. The function signature is odd, though, because the `[]` conveys that the argument should be an array, and I can't imagine what else to give it besides a single element `argv`

Comment: FYI: http://www.cdecl.org/ translates it to _declare argv as array of pointer to pointer to char_

Comment: @Motti: Which is wrong when argv is a function parameter.

Comment: Sounds like you stumbled upon a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `main` definition is `main(int argc, char * argv[])` and you want to send `argv` via pointer, you will do `Init( &argc, &argv )`. And the corresponding parameter can be `char ** argv[]`.

Comment: @Deduplicator just curious, is it well defined behaviour to modify `argc` and `argv`?

Comment: @i486: Of course! I should have looked at main first. It's exactly as you said.

Comment: @Deduplicator: stage is a robotic simulation envronment which may include several robotic controllers.  The Init function passes the command line arguments  to all the controllers in the simulation.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that this Init function will make changes to the argc and argv that main has received, so it needs pointers to them.

If the library uses some program arguments, the Init function can handle them, and then remove those arguments from the argument list before it is processed by the rest of the program.

Answer (score 1):

`char** argv[]` is an array of `char**`, IOW an array of pointers to pointers to `char`s, or more likely an array of pointers to null-terminated character strings, eg:

```
char *str1 = "...";
char *str2 = "....";

char** argv[2];
argv[0] = &str1;
argv[1] = &str2;
```

However, if `argv` is coming from `main()` itself, then `char**` is a typo, it must be `char*` instead:

```
char* argv[]
```

But if `argv` is coming from some library instead, it very well could be wrapping the original `argv` array from `main()` inside its own array, in which case `char**[]` might make sense so it can point at the original strings and not have to copy them.