# difficulty in understanding c pointers when it is on it's own (Part 2)

Tags: c, pointers

I asked this question when I saw actual multiplication and everyone helped clear understanding of it.(so I much appreciate it).

However, this continues to bother me in different situation.

For an example,

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[] )
```

Why isn't above written like below?

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[] )
```

Is there differences? Sometimes I see some funky location of * and I just don't understand why they sometimes seem to float around wherever they like(or whoever knew what they were doing I guess).

Comment: There is no difference as far as the compiler is concerned.  People choose different styles based on their or their team's preferences.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use char\*\* argv or char\* argv\[\] in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779910/should-i-use-char-argv-or-char-argv-in-c)

Comment: you can even write `char*argv` as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: The bottom line is **the compiler is smart enough** to know when to treat `*` as a `multiplication` or a `dereference` operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointer declarations in C++: placement of the asterisk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180401/pointer-declarations-in-c-placement-of-the-asterisk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, whitespace doesn't matter.  You could write it as

```
char *argv[]
```

or

```
char* argv[ ]
```

or

```
char      *        argv     [              ]
```

or even

```
char*argv[]
```

All four forms are parsed as `char (*argv[])`; the `*` operator is part of the *declarator* (as is the `[]` operator).

During compilation, your source code is broken up into *tokens*; informally speaking, a token is the smallest meaningful part of a program (keywords, operators, identifiers, literals, punctuators, etc.).  Tokens are grouped into expressions and statements according to the language grammar.

C's tokenizing algorithm is "greedy"; it will try to form the longest possible tokens from the source text, so sometimes you need to separate tokens with whitespace.  For example, if the compiler sees the text `"charfoo;"`, it will tokenize it into `charfoo` and `;` (the `;` is a separate token, since the `';'` character isn't part of an identifier).  It doesn't recognize `char` as a separate token, since it's not looking for specific keywords at this stage.  In order for it to be recognized as a declaration, you need *at least* one whitespace character between `char` and `foo`: `"char foo;"`.  Whitespace, like `';'`, isn't part of an identifier (or any other token), so it separates the `char` and `foo` tokens from each other.  Since whitespace has no meaning beyond separating tokens at this stage, it doesn't matter whether you use one space or ten or a hundred; `"char         foo        ;"` works just as well.

Throw the `'*'` character into the mix, though, and you don't need the whitespace: `"char*foo;"` will be tokenized into `char`, `*`, `foo`, `;`, because the `'*'` character, like a whitespace and `';'` characters, isn't part of an identifier.  It's a distinct token all its own.  Adding whitespace between those tokens doesn't hurt, but as far as the compiler is concerned, it doesn't change anything.

Thus, `char * argv[]` is tokenized as `char`, `*`, `argv`, `[`, and `]`.  Because you have `*` separating `char` and `argv`, it doesn't matter how much or how little whitespace comes between them.

At this point, the compiler uses the language grammar to determine how the sequence of tokens should be interpreted.  `char` is a *type specifier*, so the compiler assumes that this is the beginning of a declaration.  Since this is a declaration, the `*` operator is interpreted as the unary indirection operator, not the binary multiplication operator.

At this point the precedence of operators comes into play.  Postfix operators like `[]` have higher precedence than unary operators, so `*a[N]` is parsed as `*(a[N])` (`a` is an `N`-element array of pointers).  Thus, `argv` is an array of pointers to `char`.

Unfortunately, there's some additional weirdness at this point; The way C handles arrays is ... *different* ... from other languages, and *this particular declaration* actually declares `argv` as a pointer to a pointer to `char`.

That, however, is a question for another day.

Answer (score 7):

The two lines of code you have shown have exactly the same meaning. C in general ignores horizontal whitespace; the only times it makes a difference are (1) inside string literals, (2) when it changes the boundaries of tokens (consider `++x` versus `+ + x`), (3) when it controls whether you are `#define`-ing a function-like or object-like macro.

In the context of a type declaration, `*` is not the binary multiplication operator, it is the *unary* pointer-to modifier, and it always affects the thing to its right.  For clarity, one *should* always write it with a space on the left and no space on the right, but the compiler does not care.

(The common-particularly-in-C++ style of cuddling the star to the *left* is *wrong*, because it's misleading: `char* a, b` *does not* declare both `a` and `b` as pointers.  `char *a, b` by contrast makes clear that the star only affects `a`.  C++ grognards will say that you shouldn't write multiple variable declarations on one line in the first place, which is a reasonable position in itself, but not a valid excuse for misleading human readers about the direction in which `*` binds.  However, this is all strictly a matter of style, again, the compiler cares not.)

Comment: Thank you all for this answer. This helps me great deal although this is the type of stuff that I Hate... one min you think you learn something but then something like that shows which completely throws me off.. thank you for stackoverflow and all the user!! thank you.

Comment: To be fair, there are times when the `T*` convention used in C++ makes the intent of the code clearer (especially when dealing with containers).  But yes, it conveys a wrong interpretation of pointer declaration syntax.  `T* p;` always parses as `T (*p);`.